# Batch SQL Server Results by Max Number of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to breakup a SQL result set into batches with a max number of rows. This will be out of a table with 75M+ rows so many of the "simple" workarounds such as using Excel or a While loop are not going to work.

The following will setup an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeamPersonMap](
[TeamPersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TeamId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonId] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

DECLARE @itemCount int = 0

WHILE (@itemCount < 5)
BEGIN
    SET @itemCount = @itemCount + 1
    DECLARE @personId int = 100
    WHILE (@personId < 105)
    BEGIN
        SET @personId = @personId + 1
        INSERT INTO TeamPersonMap (TeamId, PersonId) VALUES (@itemCount, @personId)             
    END
END
```

Now we can run the following query:

```
SELECT  DENSE_RANK()OVER (ORDER BY  PersonId) as BatchGroupId, *
FROM TeamPersonMap ORDER BY PersonId
```

This will be the result set:

```
BatchId TeamPersonId    TeamId  PersonId
1             1              1  101
1             6              2  101
1             11             3  101
1             16             4  101
1             21             5  101
2             22             5  102
2             17             4  102
2             12             3  102
```

If the rule says the max batch size is 3 and the PersonId must be the same I need to query to get a final BatchId that looks like the following.

```
BatchId TeamPersonId    TeamId  PersonId
1             1              1  101
1             6              2  101
1             11             3  101
2             16             4  101
2             21             5  101
3             22             5  102
3             17             4  102
3             12             3  102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use row_number partitioned by personid to get a ranking for each row that resets back to 1 whenever a new personid is encountered. Then you can divide that by 3 (or whatever number you want for batch size) and use the a floor function to flatten out the resulting numbers into integers. You now have a batch ID for each row, but it still resets back to 1 when it reaches a new personID, so you're not done. You can then do a dense_rank() that ranks by personid plus our new "batchid_person_specific" column and get a global batchid for all rows.

Sql Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c75d/18

The result looks like this:

```
with qwry as (
SELECT  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId order by TeamPersonId) as rownum_nofloor
, floor((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId order by TeamPersonId)-1)/3)+1 as batchid_person_specific
, *
FROM TeamPersonMap 
  )
select 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PersonId, batchid_person_specific) as BatchGroupId_Final
,* from qwry
ORDER BY PersonId
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
| BATCHGROUPID_FINAL | ROWNUM_NOFLOOR | BATCHID_PERSON_SPECIFIC | TEAMPERSONID | TEAMID | PERSONID |
|--------------------|----------------|-------------------------|--------------|--------|----------|
|                  1 |              1 |                       1 |            1 |      1 |      101 |
|                  1 |              2 |                       1 |            6 |      2 |      101 |
|                  1 |              3 |                       1 |           11 |      3 |      101 |
|                  2 |              4 |                       2 |           16 |      4 |      101 |
|                  2 |              5 |                       2 |           21 |      5 |      101 |
|                  3 |              1 |                       1 |            2 |      1 |      102 |
|                  3 |              2 |                       1 |            7 |      2 |      102 |
|                  3 |              3 |                       1 |           12 |      3 |      102 |
|                  4 |              4 |                       2 |           17 |      4 |      102 |
|                  4 |              5 |                       2 |           22 |      5 |      102 |
|                  5 |              1 |                       1 |            3 |      1 |      103 |
|                  5 |              2 |                       1 |            8 |      2 |      103 |
|                  5 |              3 |                       1 |           13 |      3 |      103 |
|                  6 |              4 |                       2 |           18 |      4 |      103 |
|                  6 |              5 |                       2 |           23 |      5 |      103 |
|                  7 |              1 |                       1 |            4 |      1 |      104 |
|                  7 |              2 |                       1 |            9 |      2 |      104 |
|                  7 |              3 |                       1 |           14 |      3 |      104 |
|                  8 |              4 |                       2 |           19 |      4 |      104 |
|                  8 |              5 |                       2 |           24 |      5 |      104 |
|                  9 |              1 |                       1 |            5 |      1 |      105 |
|                  9 |              2 |                       1 |           10 |      2 |      105 |
|                  9 |              3 |                       1 |           15 |      3 |      105 |
|                 10 |              4 |                       2 |           20 |      4 |      105 |
|                 10 |              5 |                       2 |           25 |      5 |      105 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this great - it works perfectly! I added a semicolon before the `with` statement to make SQL happy - SQL Fiddle didn't care but SSMS 2008 seems to at certain times.

Comment: No problem. Semicolons go at the end of sql statements not the beginning so your  semicolon issue probably means that you have a previous sql statement in the same worksheet that is missing its ending semicolon.